# Sending an img tag in HTML through Java Web Server

Tags: java, html, image, server, webserver

I made a Java web server and I'm trying to send an image with the HTML img tag. This is parts of the code:

```
try {
    socket = server.accept();
    System.out.println(socket.getRemoteSocketAddress() + " has connected");

    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
    out.write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n");
    out.write("Content-type: text/html\r\n");
    out.write("\r\n");
    //problem starts
    out.write("<img src=\"file:///Users/Reno/Desktop/MyServer/html/images/GG9/fbicon.jpg\" alt=\"Facebook Icon\">");

    out.close();
    socket.close();


} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I've put in the path to the image file in the `src` tag in img tag. The connection works fine but the image doesn't show up and instead the alt text is shown. Before I added an alt text, there is only a blank page on the client's browser when connected to the server.

I also tried changing the src path to `"html/images/GG9/fbicon.jpg"` and instead a question mark in blue box shows up. I then changed again to a non-existing src path like `"fakepath"` and a question mark also shows up. That means the server or client must have read something with the current src path that starts with `"file:///"`.

How can I fix this and please show the correct code.

Comment: Your browser might not allow mixed protocols (i.e. your page being served over HTTP and your image over the file protocol). It would be a serious security problem if it did.

Comment: I think the comments made on your previous post still apply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a similar problem using meteor when creating an `<Image/>` element. Here are two possibe solutions:

- make sure the image file you wish to import is in a public file usable within your project. In other words, make sure you have the right to acess the image within the folder you have created for it, if you do not, you may or may not see an error message upon load
- prioritize using relative paths like : `./mypictures/Image.jpg` rather than absolute paths like `project/mypictures/Image.jpg`. Certain browsers like Google Chrome block the upload of Images on the client side if the reference path is absolute for security reasons. Again, you may not always have an error message generated because of this, though you should see in your browser something along the lines of `acess not allowed`

Hope this helped!
D.

Comment: I'm using Safari. Also the image is located here: `MyServer/html/images/GG9/fbicon.jpg` while the program is in `MyServer/test/test.java`

Comment: Is the working directory the test folder or MyServer folder in this case?

Comment: Your working directory is MyServer in this case. The file you want to make sure is public is the html file therefore. However, you could already try a quick test to make sure the problem does not come from somewhere else. Try replacing the src filepath by the url tag of the image (get an image off of internet and copy paste its url in the src prop). The image should load normally, therefore the problem should be coming from either the filepath (check the extension is .jpg and not .jpeg for example) or the acessibility of the file

Comment: You're welcome!
If this answered your problem, make sure to mark it as the answer so others can see this question as answered when they will search similar issues =)